# How do you create a Windows File Share package repository with octopus?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, octopus-deploy

My NuGet package, apparently due to some security issues, doesn't get downloaded through octopus during deployment attempt.
"The package could not be downloaded from NuGet. If you are getting a package verification error, try switching to a Windows File Share package repository to see if that helps."

How do you switch to a Windows File Share package repository and what does this actually mean?

Can I use octopus to copy all my dll files FROM my drop location (as set in the Visual studio build) TO another server/repository? Is that what the windows file share is all about?

Comment: Are you pushing into the [built-in Octopus NuGet feed](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/package-repositories/pushing-packages-to-the-built-in-repository)?

Answer (score 0):

Nuget supports (at least) two protocols for fetching nuget packages:

- HTTP based "REST" api
- windows file share

that means that if you run nuget from the command line and you have packages stored at \\someserver\someshare you can install packages from that share like this:

```
nuget install somepackage -source \\someserver\someshare
```

So. In this case, I think you want to try to

- put the packages that you've created on a file share that you own. Make the file share available to whatever account is running your Octopus server/tentacle.
- Specify this location as your repository source in octopus.

While this will solve your problem in short term you probably have a connection issue between your octopus server and your myget service endpoint. In the long run you probably want to fix that. Try to logon to the octopus server with the account that is running your OD server and try to access the myget feeds using the nuget commandline tool (you probably have to install that first...)